# Mailer Settings - Method Not Implemented

Tags: civimail, settings, administer, system

The mailer settings page does not display.

Method Not Implemented
GET to /fun/wp-admin/admin.php not supported.
Additionally, a 501 Method Not Implemented error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This is a new install of 4.7.30 on WordPress